# Where exactly does laravel require the illuminate folder?

Tags: php, laravel, directory, composer-php, autoload

Looking at the laravel composer.json it seems to autoload the app directory but not the laravel illuminate framework.

It is listed as a require in the composer file. So ok, you can do a composer install and it will pull in the framework to the vendor directory. But where does the laravel app require the illuminate framework now for usage? Maybe I'm lacking composer knowledge here but I can't figure it out.

Looking at the illuminate environment it seems to come with it's own composer file that autoloads its entire folder.

I'm trying to look at the laravel structure because I'm currently working on a little project of my own with a src directory and an app directory but I can't seem to autoload both folder with something like this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Cinematix\\": "src",
            "App\\": "app"
        }
    }
}
```

Should this be able to work? If not, how would I implement something like this? Make a php package of my src folder myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer creates `vendor/autoload.php` which is then required by Laravel in `bootstrap/autoload.php`.

The way composer works is when you update or install a package it will regenerate that file by scanning each of the packages `composer.json` files, so theres conveniently just 1 file you need to include in your project to load all of your dependencies.

As for your own package, what you have there should work. Have you run `composer dump-autoload` after updating your `composer.json`?